# Create Backup controller in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am not experienced in programming. I am trying to create a controller in laravel that backups tables. The tables are backed up correctly, but I've received some remarks that my code can easily be broken. I've been trying to do my best, but I'm really exhausted and getting frustrated. **I have a table, and each row in the table takes from 1 to 10 MB of memory. Total rows in table 100. The maximum amount of memory (memory_limit) is set to 35 MB.** What would be the best way solve this problem? I really appreciate any suggestion or help. This is my code:

1. The BackupController class

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
   use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared; // set the fetch mode
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
   use Carbon\Carbon;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use DB;
   use App\Post;
   use App\User;
   use App\Jobs\BackupTableJob;
   use Artisan;

   class BackupController extends Controller
   {
       const MAX_VALUE = 35000; //kilobytes 

       public function lockTable()
       {
           // lock all tables
           DB::unprepared('FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;');
       }

       public function setQueueJob(User $user, Post $post)
       {
           BackupTableJob::dispatch($user, $post)
               ->delay(Carbon::now()
               ->addSeconds(5));
           // Artisan::call('queue:work');     
       }

       public function unlockTable()
       {
           // unlock all tables
           DB::unprepared('UNLOCK TABLES');
       }

       public function queryFetch($data)
       {
           $pdo  = DB::connection()->getPdo();
           $stmt = $pdo->prepare($data);
           $stmt->execute();
           // $stmt = $pdo->query($data);
           $results = $stmt->fetch();
           return $results;
       }

       public function create(Request $request)
       {
           $this->setPdoMode();
           $numTables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES");
           $countUserRecords = User::count();
           $countPostRecords = Post::count();

           return view('backup', compact('numTables','countUserRecords', 'countPostRecords'));
       }

       public function setPdoMode()
       {
           \Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function($event) {
           $event->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);});
       }

       // public function backup(Request $request, User $user, Post $post)
       public function backup(Request $request, User $user, Post $post)
       {
          $this->setQueueJob($user, $post);          
          if ($request->all()) {
              $tables = request('table');
              $output = '';     
              foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {  
                  $this->lockTable();
                  $show_table_query = $this->queryFetch("SHOW CREATE TABLE {$table}");
                  $output .="\n" . $show_table_query[1] . ";\n";
                  $this->setPdoMode();
                  $single_result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
                  $output .= $this->getTableData($single_result, $table);
                  $output .= $this->cacheData($table, $output); 
              }
              if ($this->checkFileSize($output)) {
                  return redirect()->route('create'); 
              }                  
           }             
           return redirect()->route('backupError'); 
       }

       // Stores the file in this location: storage/app
       public function download($output)
       {
           $dt = Carbon::now();
           $file_name = 'backup_on[' . $dt->format('y-m-d H-i-s') . '].sql';
           Storage::disk('local')->put($file_name, $output);
       }

       public function getTableData($single_result, $table) 
       {
           $this->unlockTable();
           $output = '';
           foreach ($single_result as $key => $table_val) {
               if ($table === "posts" || $table === "users") {
                   $output .= "\nINSERT INTO $table("; 
                   $output .= "" .addslashes(implode(", ", array_keys($table_val))) . ") VALUES(";
                   $output .= "'" . addslashes(implode("','", array_values($table_val))) . "');\n";
               }  
           }
           // $output .= $this->cacheData($table, $output);   
           return $output;
       }

       public function checkFileSize($file)
       {
           $file_size = strlen($file);
           // convert bytes to kilobytes 
           $file_size = round($file_size / 1024, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
           if ($file_size <= self::MAX_VALUE) {
               $this->download($file);
               return true;
           } 
           return false;               
       }

       public function cacheData($table, $data)
       {
           // $table = $table;
           $start = microtime(true);
           $data = Cache::remember('table', 10, function() use ($table){
               return DB::table($table)->get();
           });
           $duration = (microtime(true) -$start) * 1000;

           \Log::info("From cache: " . $duration .' ms');
           return $data;
       }
    }
   ```
2. BackupTableJob class

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Jobs;

   use App\User;
   use App\Post;
   use App\Http\Controllers\BackupController;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
   use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

   class BackupTableJob implements ShouldQueue
   {
       use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable; //SerializesModels;

       protected $user;
       protected $post;

       /**
        * Create a new job instance.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function __construct(User $user, Post $post)
       // public function __construct()
       {
           $this->user = $user;
           $this->post = $post;
       }

       /**
        * Execute the job.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function handle()
       {
           // $this->user->save();
           // $this->post->save();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am trying to use Queue to handle memory limitations, but I am not sure if I am implementing things correctly. Please, What do I need to improve my code? What would be the appropriate way to manage the memory? I do not need use any third-party library at all. Just pure PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to process that data with PHP. You can simply use raw SQL queries in laravel:

```
SELECT *
INTO tableToBeBackedUp
FROM currentTable;
```

Comment: Wokes, thanks! So, I need to take into account the amount of data stored. So, I am injecting user and post tables using Queue Job. Is that a good way for managing the time and memory limits of execution?

Comment: If you're just creating snapshots of tables at given time, pure SQL will do. Let Laravel execute that SQL periodically using its [scheduling system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) and you're set.

Comment: There is literally no reason for you to pull that data out of the database, store it in PHP temporarily and insert it back to the database, it can be all done without ever leaving the DB.

Comment: Wokes, I'm not inserting anything back to the database. That query does not execute. It just holds the insert query along with the data.

Comment: I misunderstood then. I figured you wanted to duplicate the table and set a different name for the new copy.